# How to prevent Robot mouseMove going out of the screen

Tags: java

I am creating an app where I control mouse movements using android phone.

The problem I am facing is, if moves the mouse to the end of the screen it continues to move without an end.

How can I prevent stop mouse movement when it reaches end of the screen. Thanks in advance.

and also how can I make the movement common in all screen resolutions?

```
public void evaluate(String message) {
        String[] data = message.split(" ");
        switch (data[0]) {
        case "M":

            try {
                n[0] = new Float(data[1]);
                n[1] = new Float(data[2]);
                Thread mouse = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        Point a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
                        int x = (int) a.getX();
                        int y = (int) a.getY();
                        double scale = 1;
                        int xnew = (int) (scale * n[1] + x);
                        int ynew = (int) (scale * n[0] + y);
                        robo.mouseMove(xnew, ynew);
                    }
                });
                mouse.run();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
            break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get current screen resolution, and check if newX and newY is in your screen.

```
if(xnew < width && ynew < height) robo.mouseMove(xnew, ynew);
```

To get screen resoultion:

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
double width = screenSize.getWidth();
double height = screenSize.getHeight();
```